# Firefox bookmarks in the Ubuntu files system

Tags: firefox, backup, bookmarks

I have accessed my crashed Ubuntu version via live USB trial. Where am I supposed to find my former Firefox bookmarks and history files in order to copy and transfer them into a new installation?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest thing to do would be copying the Firefox profile folder over

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Linux

The bookmarks are actually stored in `bookmarks.html` if you just want that.

Comment: ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default   should I insert this into terminal?

Comment: @Andy the xxxxxxxx is a random string generated, you need to take a look at yours and take it from there;-)

Comment: I found the hidden folder mozilla on the previous version but I cannot access its contents due to the password protection in the previuos version. could you recommend any method of opening such a folder from the trial ubuntu on live USB or from a newly installed system?

Comment: @Andy Can you explain "password protection"? Do you mean the bookmarks or the profile folder (or filesystem it resides)? If you know the password you set, try to run firefox -p /mount_point/home/user/.mozilla/xxxxxxxx.default and see if you can input the password and export the bookmarks.

Comment: thank you a lot I managed to restore my broken boot and access the system :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have never used the firefox option Bookmarks->Show All Bookmarks-> Import and Backup -> Export Bookmarks to
HTML, then you will never see a file, `bookmarks.html`.
In such a case, you can probably copy over the history files stored in
    ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/bookmarkbackups/
where xxxxxxxx.default is a FF assigned directory.
And then, don't forget to export the bookmarks to wherever you want them. 
It will be stored at /bookmarks.html

Comment: After copying across the most recent backup, I restarted firefox and opened the library. I clicked "import and backup" then on mouse over, the restore option showed the backup file. Select this and the bookmarks are imported into the browser.

Comment: @dmkonlinux This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the old `.mozilla` folder into your home folder, after which you can select the appropriate backup through *Import and Backup* → *Restore* within FireFox (or IceCat) under *Bookmarks* → *Show All Bookmarks*.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't exported your bookmarks to a `bookmark.html` file, you can still replace your current bookmarks with your old ones :)

- Click on *Bookmarks->Manage Bookmarks* or simply use `Ctrl+Shift+O`.
- Select *Import and Backup->Restore->Choose file*
- Navigate to your **old** `.mozilla` folder. make sure you right click *Show Hidden Files*
- Keep the JSON preselected filter on and in one of the folders of under the `firefox` directory you should find a `bookmarkbackups` folder. Simply click on the latest `.json` file!